# How to import / execute a SQL DDL file in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a .ddl file from the physical model in Erwin database modeler and I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to import / execute this file in SQL Server Management Studio to have the .ddl file create the tables, keys, and data types in the database I created.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way. you have to generate the DDL into separate scripts and then manually run the scripts. please monitor once the scripts have run successfully.

At times the database compare post  create database using their generated DDL would find differences in column order on indexes or column nullability. so please verify thoroughly.